# How to write one line of text at the bottom of each page in the article document class？

Tags: graphics, minipage, text, article, crop-image

I need to write one line of text (actually a line of text and an image, es:phone icon and telephone number) as the last line of **each page**. How can I do that? I've tried minpage environment but it doesn't write on the last line of the page, but just in the last line of my current class.

Thank you

Renato

Comment: Have you tried `\AtEndDocument{<stuff>}`?

Comment: but this put the word stuff at the end of document I have just one line per page

Answer (score 2):

Use `fancyhdr` to create a page style which could produce such a line at the bottom of each page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bbding}%for \Phone
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[C]{\raisebox{-0.08\baselineskip}{\Phone} 20230314%
\\[1\baselineskip]\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}%


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\lipsum[2]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

By the way, please give a minimal working sample when to ask a question next time.

Comment: it works but put the number just on my last page (not on page 1,2,3) and I would put it at the place of the page number (that I've disabled with \thispagestyle{empty})

Comment: @RenatoP -- `\thispagestyle(empty}` wipes out all headers and footers, including what you just added.  What you need to do instead is define an *alternate* page style.

Answer (score 1):

This combines `\AddToHook` with `tikzpagenodes` (easy to implement).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bbding}%for \Phone
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\advance\footskip by \baselineskip% reserve more space, if needed

\newcommand{\myfoot}{{\Phone} (213) 555-1212}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[below=\dp\strutbox] at (current page text area.south) {\myfoot};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\renewcommand{\myfoot}{{\Phone} (213) 555-3406}%
\lipsum[2]
    
\end{document}
```

---

Alternative **not** using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bbding}%for \Phone
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\advance\footskip by \baselineskip% reserve more space, if needed

\newcommand{\myfoot}{{\Phone} (213) 555-1212}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\ifodd\value{page}
    \put({1in+\oddsidemargin},{-\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight+\baselineskip})
      {\makebox[\textwidth]{\myfoot}}
  \else
    \put({1in+\evensidemargin},{-\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight+\baselineskip})
      {\makebox[\textwidth]{\myfoot}}
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\renewcommand{\myfoot}{{\Phone} (213) 555-3406}%
\lipsum[2]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: this (with and without tikz) are perfect. But I have to change text in different pages. Is it possible? How can I achieve it?

Comment: Replace the text `{\Phone} (213) 555-1212}` with a macro.

Comment: how can I insert it on any page? wich macro can I use for : e.mail; fb addr; instangram addr?

Comment: I've repeated This lines on the second page: \AddToHook{shipout/background}{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[below=\dp\strutbox] at (current page text area.south) {{\Phone} (213) 111-222};
  \end{tikzpicture}},  but I've two times the same footer with different text that overlap

Comment: I don't know the AddTHook statement, but this is what can work for me. But how can I change the content (phone in firs page, email on second and so on) in every page? – 
RenatoP
 2 secs ago   Edit

Comment: I modified the solution to use a macro (`\myfoot`) and changed it between pages 1 and 2.

Comment: `\AddToHook` is a relatively new feature.  On my computer is it documented in `C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\doc\latex\base\lthooks-doc.pdf`.  In particular, `\AddToHook{shipout/background}` is similar to the old everypage package.

Comment: sorry John, but I still don't undestand what I’ve to do. Can you please made me an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144632/discussion-between-john-kormylo-and-renatop).